# Vertically top align sub children in a div html

Tags: html, css

I am using following code

```
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px; width: 800px; height:110px; display:inline-block;" >

          <img src="images/about_us_logo.png" alt="" width="104" height="110" />
          <label class="aboutText" ><?php echo $store['description'] ?></label>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;" >

          <img src="images/webaddress_about.png" alt="" width="70" height="67" />
          <label class="aboutText" ><?php echo $store['website'] ?></label>

    </div>

    <br />
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;" >

          <img src="images/email_about.png" alt="" width="70" height="49" />
          <label class="aboutText" ><?php echo $store['email'] ?></label>

    </div>
    <br />
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px; display:inline-block;" >

          <img src="images/phone_about.png" alt="" width="50" height="55" />
          <label class="aboutText" ><?php echo $store['phone'] ?></label>

    </div>



.aboutText
{
    margin: 10px 10x  10px 20px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: #C7C7C7;
    width: 500px;
    height:110px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The result is as under

[image]

The problem is the image and text is not aligned. I need the text to be placed on top align with image
2- The logo along with its description is overlapping the image below , what should i do to fix it

Comment: Please avoid using inline styles. if you simply look at you're code, you can see that's lots of css is duplicated. it also makes your code unreadable and hard to work with, especially for others…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add this css rule to align sub-children to top:

```
img,label{
    vertical-align:top; /* vertically align */
}
```

But i think `middle` will fit best for this one

```
img,label{
    vertical-align:middle; /* vertically align */
}
```

### [**Demo with top**](http://jsfiddle.net/eGQD8/1/)

### [**Demo with middle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eGQD8/2/)

In case if description text is too long, this scenario will always be useful, Do it like this, add some css rule to your label CSS along with the above rules:

```
.aboutText
{
    margin: 10px 10x  10px 20px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: #C7C7C7;
 /* width: 110px;*/ /*Get rid of height here
    height:500px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;

    word-wrap:break-word;/* added new rule*/
    display:inline-block;/* added new rule*/
    text-align:left;   /* added new rule*/
}
```

### [**Final Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eGQD8/6/)

Hope you need this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the left align property for images

```
img
{
 text-align:left;
}
```